# Как написать lambda функцию с условием которая проходит по строкам всего датафрейма?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

Например есть простенький датафрейм:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Apple', True],[2,'Apple', False],[3,'Orange', False],[4,'Orange', True]],
         columns=['count','fruit','fresh'])
```

Мне нужно написать lambda функцию с условием описанным ниже и применить ее к датафрейму, чтобы получить новый столбец через apply:

```
lambda x: 1 if 2<=x.count<=3 and x.fruit=='Apple' or x.fresh==True else 0
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda...
```

Comment: что значит "по смыслу похожую"? что эта функция должна возвращать? и что такое python.pd?

Comment: @strawdog переформулировал, функция должна вернуть 1 или 0 в зависимости от условия описанного выше, pd - сокращение от пандас

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вам, вероятно, просто нужно указать axis. Только определитесь с приоритетом условий OR и AND:

```
df['new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if (2<=x["count"]<=3)&
                         (x["fruit"]=="Apple")|
                         (x["fresh"]==True) else 0, axis=1)
```

df:

```
   count   fruit  fresh  new_col
0      1   Apple   True        1
1      2   Apple  False        1
2      3  Orange  False        0
3      4  Orange   True        1
​
```

Comment: Спасибо! пробовал до этого добавлять axis, но не работало, видимо из-за того что не расставил скобки

Answer (score 0):

при желании тут можно обойтись без лямбды:

```
df['new_col'] = ((df['count'].isin([2,3]))&(df['fruit']=='Apple')|df['fresh'])*1
print(df)
'''
   count   fruit  fresh  new_col
0      1   Apple   True        1
1      2   Apple  False        1
2      3  Orange  False        0
3      4  Orange   True        1
```